# TypeError: Cannot read property 'varName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is my code. I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property ''` of undefined and errors like that.

```
const data = cache.actions[cache.index];
let varName = this.evalMessage(data.varName, cache);
let storage = parseInt(data.storage);
let info = parseInt(data.info);
let time = parseInt(data.time);
const { msg } = cache
const { guild } = cache

if (guild.varName === undefined) {
guild.varName = new Set();
}
    if (message.guild.varName.has(msg.author.id)) {
            channel.send("info");
            console.log("Restriction active!");
} else {

        message.guild.varName.add(msg.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {

        message.guild.varName.delete(msg.author.id);
        }, time);
        
    }`
```

Comment: where "message" comes from?

Comment: @TheRealPikachu You don't want to use guild.varName but guild[varName] everywhere to use dynamic object property.

Comment: What line is your error at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two main issues here. First, you don't have a message collector anywhere in this code. A message collector would be something like

```
client.on('message', function() {
    //some code here
}
```

This waits for the bot to receive a message and then does whatever is inside the function. The second issue I see is that you have a variable `varName` and you're trying to access a property of `guild` using that variable. In your code, you used dot notation, but dot notation doesn't work when trying to access a property with a variable. Your code looks for a property of guild called `"varName"` (note that it's a string), when you should be looking for a property called *whatever the value of `varName` is*. To do that, you would use `guild[varName]`.